# Suppose $A, B$, and C are sets. Prove that $C\subset A\Delta B \Leftrightarrow C \subset A \cup B$ and $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

The problem statement is in the title.

I'm proving a problem in class and I need to show the above containment. I've drawn some Venn diagrams to make sure the containment makes sense, and it does to me, but I am still having problems proving this statement.
I know that $A \Delta B = (A \cup B) – ( A \cap B)$, and I can see through the Venn diagrams I have drawn how [$C \subset A \Delta B$ iff $C \subset A \cup B$ and $A \cap B \cap C =\emptyset $], but I am having trouble explaining this to someone else.

Comment: Please make the question's body self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try necessity. Let $$c \in C \subseteq A \Delta B = (A \cup B) - (A \cap B).$$ Then, $c \in A \cup B$ and $c \not \in A \cap B$. Thus,

- every $c \in C$ also satisfies $c \in A \cup B$, hence, $C \subseteq A \cup B$;
- every $c \in C$ also satisfies $c \not \in A \cap B$, hence $C \cap A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Can you go the other way?

Comment: C ⊆ A Δ B  =  
C ⊆ (A ⋃ B) ⋂ ¬(A ⋂ B)  =  
C ⊆ (A ⋃ B) ⋂ (¬A ⋂ ¬B)  =  
C ⊆ (A ⋂ ¬B) ⋃ (B ⋂ ¬A)   
Since c ϵ C also satisfies either A or B, but not A and B, the statement A ⋂ B ⋂ C must be an empty or null set.
I’m still learning, so please tell me where I am either incorrect or where I could clean up my terminology.

Comment: @GabeCarr not sure what you mean. The event $z \in X - Y = X \cap \bar{Y}$ happens if and only if $z \in X$ and $z \not \in Y$.

Comment: What I was trying to convey was that C is a subset of A or B, but that C is not a subset of A and B.

Comment: @GabeCarr the phrase "the statement A ⋂ B ⋂ C must be an empty or null set" is wrong: $A \cap B \cap C$ is *not* a statement, and statements cannot be empty or null sets. What is meant to say is that the *set* $A \cap B \cap C$ is empty, i.e. $A \cap B \cap C = \emptyset$

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this as a simplification problem, which is straightforwardly solved by expanding the definitions from set theory and then simplifying using the rules of logic.

So I would start on the most complex side, and calculate as follows:
\begin{align}
& C \subseteq A \cup B \;\land\; A \cap B \cap C = \varnothing \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definitions of $\;\subseteq\;$; basic property of $\;\varnothing\;$"} \\
&
  \langle \forall x :: x \in C \;\Rightarrow\; x \in A \cup B \rangle
  \;\land\;
  \langle \forall x :: \lnot(x \in A \cap B \cap C) \rangle
  \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\cup\;$, and of $\;\cap\;$ twice; merge quantifications"} \\
& \langle \forall x ::
    (x \in C \;\Rightarrow\; x \in A \lor x \in B)
    \;\land\;
    \lnot(x \in A \land x \in B \land x \in C)
  \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: write $\;P \Rightarrow Q\;$ as $\;\lnot P \lor Q\;$ in left part;} \\
& \qquad \phantom{\text{"}}\text{DeMorgan for right part} \\
& \qquad \phantom{\text{"}}\text{-- to get everything in similar shape"} \\
& \langle \forall x ::
    (x \not\in C \lor x \in A \lor x \in B)
    \;\land\;
    (x \not\in A \lor x \not\in B \lor x \not\in C)
  \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: extract common disjunct $\;x \not\in C\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \not\in C \lor (
    (x \in A \lor x \in B)
    \;\land\;
    (x \not\in A \lor x \not\in B)
  ) \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"logic: simplify $\;(P \lor Q) \land (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)\;$ to $\;P \not\equiv Q\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in C \;\Rightarrow\; (
    x \in A \not\equiv x \in B
  ) \rangle \\
\equiv & \qquad \text{"definition of $\;\triangle\;$; definition of $\;\subseteq\;$"} \\
& C \subseteq A \triangle B \\
\end{align}
This completes the proof.

In the last step I used a not-too-well-known definition of set difference:
$$
x \in A \triangle B \;\equiv\; x \in A \not\equiv x \in B
$$